# How integrate one React app into another React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create two React apps. One will be the main app, and the other will be a plugin app that I can install/add to the main app. Both apps have to be stand-alone apps and can work on their own, and don’t have to depend on each other at all.

I need to come up with a system that can make these two apps work together.

My main concern is I don’t understand how I can connect the second app to the first so it shows its content inside the first one.

It should be something like WordPress and its plugins.

I understand it should be some plugin registry and dynamic plugin loader so it can easily switch between selected plugin apps.

I have tried Modular Federation and Micro Frontends, but this is not exactly what I need, as there are hardcoded changes that should be made in the main app code to import. But what I need is some kind of plugin loading system.

Maybe there are already open-source systems like this that I can check?

Or some guide information on how to develop the system like this?

Comment: An App ultimately is just a component. You can create an NPM package that has your app, and as long as you export that app you could use it in another app. There's caveats you might run into, but that's a good starting point. Any issues you run into later solve them one at a time.